# How can I use 'InsertQuery' with generic record and table types

Tags: java, jooq

I have this method:

```
public InsertQuery<Record> getInsertQuery(List<?> pojoList, TableImpl<Record> table) {
    InsertQuery<Record> insertQuery = ctx.insertQuery(table);
    pojoList.forEach(pojo -> insertQuery.addRecord(ctx.newRecord(table, pojo)));
    insertQuery.setReturning();
    return insertQuery;
}
```

It basically takes in a `pojoList`, to be inserted to the given `table`, and returns an `InsertQuery<Record>` which can be executed to insert one or more rows. But when I'm calling this method like:

```
    try (DSLContext ctx = DslContextFactory.getDslContext();
             InsertQuery<AttachmentsRecord> insertQuery = new AttachmentQueries(ctx)
                     .getInsertQuery(pojos, JOOQ_GENERATED_TABLE)) {
                         // do something.

    }
```

It complains on the `JOOQ_GENERATED_TABLE` saying the required type is `TableImpl<Record>`, but something else is provided. How can I give a generic type for jooq generated tables and records? Could really use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your utility to this:

```java
public <R extends Record> InsertQuery<R> getInsertQuery(
    List<?> pojoList,
    Table<R> table // I recommend using Table<R> because TableImpl<R> is internal API
) {
    InsertQuery<R> insertQuery = ctx.insertQuery(table);
    pojoList.forEach(pojo -> insertQuery.addRecord(ctx.newRecord(table, pojo)));
    insertQuery.setReturning();
    return insertQuery;
}
```